# Android Fill horizontal custom view in actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I want to custom `ActionBar` and the customview fill all the `customBar`,
But having a space a left of `actionbar` (with blue color).
How to delete this space?

this is my problems:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/05hyj4r2z8du80b/device-2014-05-28-114146.png

MainActivity:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View customViewActionBar = inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_custom, null);
getActionBar().setCustomView(customViewActionBar);
```

Comment: this is custom_actionbar:

Comment: can you share your actionbar layout code ?